# Upgrade mysql 5.5.40 to 5.6 on centos 6.4

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, upgrade

I can't find a repo to add to my repolist that has an update for mysql 5.6. Does anyone know how to do this? I tried this [[link]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-from-official-yum-repositories) but it broke everything. I was getting a mysql_connect() undefined function after I ran that update. I tried updating the php-mysql lib but there were a lot of dependencies that didn't work out. After 5 hours of trying to fix dependencies and running updates, I ended up wiping php, apache, mysql and reinstalling with yum. Now I'm running PHP 5.6.1 and apache mysql 5.5.40

Comment: What is your business need for that combination?

Comment: I want to use the TIMESTAMP with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in multiple fields.

Comment: "I was getting a mysql_connect() undefined function after I ran that update." This would have nothing to do with a MySQL update and everything to do with a PHP update. You likely just needed `php55-mysql` or something.

Comment: If you need to be that bleeding-edge, I don't think CentOS is the right platform for you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't update php until after I got that error though. So something else happened with the mysql update. I may have removed php-mysql somehow but none the less I couldn't reinstall php-mysql without a hoard of dependencies that wouldn't work together with all the other libs.

Comment: I wouldn't consider 5.6 to be bleeding edge.

Comment: Given that stock C6 is at mysql-5.1.73 and PHP 5.3.3, I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do the following

## STEP #01 : [mysqldump all the data except the mysql schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69667/877)

## STEP #02 : Backup the mysql grants

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" | mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -N | sed 's/$/;/g' > Grants.sql
```

## STEP #03 : Download MySQL 5.6

- [MySQL's Repository](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
- [MariaDB (Formerly Known as SkySQL) Repository](https://downloads.mariadb.com/archive/index/p/mysql)

## STEP #04 : Uninstall MySQL 5.5

## STEP #05 : Install MySQL 5.6

## STEP #06 : Load Grants.sql from `STEP #02`

## STEP #07 : Load Data from `STEP #01`

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: This worked although ... I didn't need the grants.sql or the data.
I ran all the steps except 6 & 7...all my data and permissions were still intact.
Thanks!

Comment: Won't it work if we use mysql_upgrade? We tried mysql_upgrade and after doing that we are not able to execute any heavy queries. It is taking forever to execute them.